# "Mindestens" vs "zumindest". Gibt es einen Unterschied?

Tags: meaning, difference, adverb

Im Internet gibt es keinen klaren Unterschied dazwischen, aber meine Lehrerin hat mich mehrmals dafür verbessert (und danach habe ich den Unterschied wieder vergessen).

Könnt ihr bitte auch ein paar Beispiele geben?

Comment: Ich bringe mindestens zwei Beispiele. Das ist zumindest ein Anfang.

Comment: Wow, die Frage ist wirklich schwer zu beantworten. Die Wörter haben eine sehr große Schnittmenge, oft können beide Synonym verwendet werden. In manchen Kontexten wäre es ungewöhnlich das eine oder andere zu verwenden, und doch würde der alleinstehende, kontextlose Satz wieder Sinn machen ("Wir brauchen mindestens 3 Stunden" vs "Wir brauchen zumindest 3 Stunden (Zeit)").

Comment: @chirlu "Ich bringe **zumindest** zwei Beispiele(, du aber keines)" -> Hier wäre *mindestens* falsch. - Im zweiten Beispiel ist es in der Tat üblicher, *zumindest* zu verwenden. Aber ich bezweifle zumindest, dass *mindestens* hier wirklich falsch wäre.

Comment: @Em1 chirlus Kommentar ist korrekt. Er hat zwei Beispiele gebracht, das sind mindestens zwei Beispiele. Man kann allerdings *auch* zumindest in deiner Bedeutung verwenden.

Comment: @Em1 Ja, manchmal bin ich zu mathematisch. Zumindest finden das andere gelegentlich. :)

Comment: @chirlu Und ich dachte, ich sei der einzige... Zumindest sind wir jetzt mindestens zu zweit!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ich nehme mal chirlus Kommentar als Aufhänger:

`Mindestens` bezieht sich meistens auf Zahlen, Größen oder andere skalierbare Sachen, d. h. um eine Quantität.

> Ich bringe mindestens zwei Beispiele.

Es könnten auch quantitativ mehr sein, also z. B. 3 Beispiel.

`Zumindest` bezieht sich zumeist auf nicht skalierbare oder nicht skalierte Sachen, d. h. um eine Qualität.

> Das ist zumindest ein Anfang.

Es könnte auch qualitativ mehr sein, also z. B. eine komplette Lösung. Es könnten aber nicht zwei Anfänge, weil das hier keinen Sinn macht.

Da es aber unklar ist, ob etwas skaliert wird oder nicht, gibt es auch Schnittmengen zwischen den Verwendungen.

Comment: Wie erklärst du dann das Duden-Beispiel "du hättest dich mindestens entschuldigen müssen"

Comment: @Toscho: Ich glaube Dir fehlen die Begriffe "Quantität vs. Qualität" für das was Du sagen willst, auch wenn es nicht richtig ist, wie Em1' Beispiel zeigt.

Comment: @Em1 Ich finde in dem Duden-Beispiel `zumindest` die bessere Wahl. Außerdem habe ich von „meistens“ und „Schnittmengen“ geschrieben.

Comment: @userunknown Danke für den Hinweis.

Answer (score 5):

Ich versuche es mal superkurz.

**Mindestens** heißt:

> > this much, if not more, more is desirable/possible

- Mindestens bis um 7 (vielleicht länger)
- mindestens 10 Euro (vielleicht mehr)

**Zumindest** heißt

> > this much, less would have been possible, more was kind of not to be expected so zumindest is the "most possible" in a situation

- Ruf zumindest an, wenn du zu spät kommst!

Deshlab funktioniert **zumindest**, wie in der Antwort von @Tosho richtig gesagt, nicht gut mit Zahlen, da dort "most possible" **höchstens** wäre.

**Zumindest** ist für mich fats ein Synonym für **wenigstens**.
Diese Unterscheidung is natürlich nicht strikt und es kann durchaus auch ein regionaler Eindruck von mir sein aber ich glaube, so kann man beide ganz gut trennen.

Comment: Ich habe schon ein Beispiel gezeigt, wo *zumindest* sehr gut mit Zahlen kooperiert und ich könnte dir noch viele zeigen. Es ist immer nur eine Frage, was man aussagen möchte.

Comment: Dann ist es vermutlich was regionales, denn "Wir brauchen zumindest 2 Stunden Zeit" klingt für mich komisch, egal welcher Kontext gegeben ist. Ich würde das nie so sagen... aber wie, gesagt, da gibt's wohl kein richtig und kein falsch.

Comment: ps.: Ich würde auch nie "zumindest 2 Beispiele" sagen :)

Comment: *Zumindest*, so wie ich es meine, modifiziert auch gar nicht die Zahl, so wie es bei *mindestens* ist. Es ist eher ein Synonym zu *immerhin*. - "Die Frage ist sehr populär. Mindestens 1000 Leute lasen sie(, wenn nicht sogar mehr)." - "Die Frage ist nicht sehr populär. Aber zumindest 100 Leute (und zwar fast genau 100 Leute) lasen sie."

Comment: Ah, ok, ich verstehe was du meinst aber in diesen Fällen würde ich (persönlich) den Satz anders bauen und sagen: "Aber zumindest haben sie 100 Leute gelesen"... zumindest also als klares Adverb von der Zahl trennen.

Comment: Würde ich meistens auch, gelingt aber auch nicht immer. Und aus meinem anderen Kommentar von gerade, als Überspitzung des Ganzen: "...wenn es **zumindest mindestens** eine signifikant große Gruppe gibt,... :D

Answer (score 1):

Wenn "zumindest" benutzt wird, geht es oft um irgendwelche (Minimal-)Verpflichtungen.

Ein anderes Wort mit ähnlicher Bedeutung ist "wenigstens", das wird für mein Gefühl aber eher umgangssprachlich benutzt ("Du hättest wenigstens mal X tun können.").

"Mindestens" ist neutraler und beschreibt eher die Realität, wird heute aber auch oft wie "zumindest" benutzt.