# “Jedenfalls” and “wenigstens”

Tags: modal-particle

The phrases *auf jeden Fall* and *auf alle Fälle* are possible alternatives for *jedenfalls*.

> 1. Vielleicht ist er krank, er sieht ***jedenfalls*** schlecht aus.
> 2. Er ist noch nicht gekommen, aber er hat sich ***jedenfalls*** entschuldigt.

Can I also replace *jedenfalls* with *wenigstens*?

Comment: In both sentences I would **not** say "auf alle Fälle". In the first sentence "auf jeden Fall" is OK but not in the second one. You can say "wenigstens" in the second but it's a little weird in the first one. In both sentence you can go with "[zumindest](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6967/1224)".

Comment: Ich finde `jedenfalls` im 2. Satz falsch. Was soll es ausdrücken? `Zumindest` ginge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Wenigstens* is a word of positivity, and often optimism and hope. You say it if you're glad that something is at least that level and not worse.

So if you said `..., er sieht wenigstens schlecht aus`, this would mean you are glad he looks at least bad. I think this is not what you have in mind and that's why *wenigstens* is not appropriate here.

In your second sentence it's a good choice to use *wenigstens* because you appreciate his sorry. That's a positive signal after the bad situation, so hope and optimistic thinking relieved it a bit.

Comment: Im Satz "Er hat wenigstens nicht gelitten" sehe ich keine Hoffnung und keinen Optimismus ausgedrückt, denn diese beziehen sich immer auf die Zukunft. Das Wort drückt eher aus `wenn auch sonst nichts gutes zu vermelden ist, so ...`.

Comment: @user unknown: OK, you're right with the *gelitten* example, I'll add `positivity` to my answer.